# Replaced RAM and now web browser flickers

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory, google-chrome, screen

I have a Macbook Pro 13-in. mid-2012, OS X Yosemite 1010.3.

I recently upgraded the RAM from 4 GB to 8 GB using Apple's guidelines:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1270

After replacing the screen and booting the system, I opened up Chrome. Whenever I type/scroll, the web browser flickers. Not the screen, just the web browser.

Any ideas what the problem is? My guess is I didn't place the RAM in correctly. Also, after lifting off the back case, I did spray the inside with canned air (as recommended, I thought) to clean the system of any dust. Would this forever damage the system?

Is it possible this is a static electricity issue? I have my doubts.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Another thought: maybe I touched the RAM cards incorrectly and damaged them? Is that possible?

Comment: If the screen newer flickers without browser window, then it is hard to believe it is the RAM.

Comment: Does it look like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fj5sho03r2lnjad/ChromeGlitches.mov?dl=0)? In my case it was a bad VGA cable. I would agree with @Buscar웃SD, though, it is unlikely to be related to the RAM.

Answer (score 1):

From what I found, it was after all the RAM. I took out both chips again and used compressed air to thoroughly clean the areas involved. After that, it seemed to work.

Of course, it could be that I hadn't had the chips in properly previously, as opposed to dust.